# How to show why "try" failed in python

Tags: python, error-handling

is there anyway to show why a "try" failed, and skipped to "except", without writing out all the possible errors by hand, and without ending the program?

example:

```
try:
    1/0
except:
    someway to show 
    "Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
         1/0
    ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero"
```

i dont want to do`if:print error 1, elif: print error 2, elif: etc...`. i want to see the error that would be shown had `try` not been there

Comment: Semi-OT: Unspecific `except` clauses are nearly always a bad idea. You should always specify which Exceptions you are planning to catch, so you don't accidentally mess something up when an unexpected Exception, say a `KeyboardInterruptException` comes along that you're then not handling correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except Exception, e:
...    print e
... 
integer division or modulo by zero
```

There are other syntactical variants, e.g.:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except Exception as e:
...    print e
... 
integer division or modulo by zero
```

More information can be found in the [errors tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: If you want to re-raise the exception (ie. halt execution, etc), use `raise e` or just `raise`.

Answer (score 8):

I often use `traceback` to log such exception to log or show on stderr:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    print 1/0
except Exception:
    s = traceback.format_exc()
    serr = "there were errors:\n%s\n" % (s)
    sys.stderr.write(serr)
```

Output will show info about line is source where exception occured:

```
there were errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\test\ex.py", line 5, in <module>
    print 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: From http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/: "When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare 'except:' clause. [...] A bare 'except:' clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems.  If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use 'except Exception:'."

Comment: OK. Added `Exception` to `except`.